# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/lib'

Tags: python, pyenv

I'm trying to use `pyenv` to manage my python versions on MacOS (Catalina). I get the error message below:

`ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/lib'`.

There are many similar questions to this one, but the solutions do not work for me. The unique component of my question has to do with its relevance to the `/lib` folder.

Here is the full trace below.

```
⇒  pyenv install 3.7.5       
WARNING: Please make sure you remove any previous custom paths from your /Users/hyang123/.pydistutils.cfg file.
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.7.5.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.5/Python-3.7.5.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.7.5...
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk
Installing pip from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py...
error: failed to install pip via get-pip.py

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.15.7 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/t1/2nf22s493sg5w56ytwzm1jvh0000gn/T/python-build.20201127214144.929
Results logged to /var/folders/t1/2nf22s493sg5w56ytwzm1jvh0000gn/T/python-build.20201127214144.929.log

Last 10 log lines:
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Users/hyang123/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (20.1.1)
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-20.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached setuptools-50.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (785 kB)
Collecting wheel
  Using cached wheel-0.35.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
Installing collected packages: pip, setuptools, wheel
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/lib'
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you running this as a regular user or as root?  What OS version are you running?  This sounds like this might be due to a tightening of security that occurs every time you advance to the next major MacOS release.

Comment: The username in the `warning ... ` and the line of `requirement ... ` do not match, that could be an issue.

Comment: @etch_45 - good catch!  That's really bizarre and troubling.  There should never be two `/Users` directories involved in the same operation.  That points to there being something messed up with your system's configuration.  Have you done much hacking on your environment paths in `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` (or the equivalents if you're using a different shell than `bash`)?  That might explain some of this.

Comment: @etch_45 My apologies, I changed the usernames manually to mask my computer's username. I have edited the trace.

Comment: @Steve I am running as root user. MacOS Catalina (10.15.7)

Comment: Ok.  I'm fairly confident that this is a Catalina thing.  You could probably write to `/lib` in earlier OSs.  There's a way to change it so you can write there again, but I don't think you want to do that.  I'd suggest that you look for an installer that is Catalina compatible, assuming that that's the problem.  Could you use Brew to install Python.  I saw in your error dump some mention of Brew, so I'm guessing that you do use it.  I'm running Catalina and recently installed P3.8.6 and P3.9.0 using Brew, and then wired them up to `pyenv`.  Works great, and you don't have to run as root.

Answer (score 0):

I use `pyenv`, but I don't use it to install my base Python versions.  I use Homebrew for that, and then I register my base Python installs with `pyenv` after the fact.  I've never had any trouble like this when I worked that way.  I don't, however, know why you can't do what you're doing.

If you're running as a regular user, and my understanding is that with `pyenv`, you should be, then I'm guessing that this is a bug either in `pyenv` or in the installer package for the Python you are trying to install.  As a regular user, you won't be able to write to `/lib`.  If the system is attempting to do so, that's incorrect given my understanding of the assumptions `pyenv` makes about the world.

If you are running as `root` such that `pyenv` should be installing into system-level directories, then I'm wondering if this problem is due to the tightening security that Apple seems to apply to each new major release of MacOS.  It may be that even as `root`, you are no longer allowed to write to `/lib`.  It would make some sense that you can write to `/usr/local/lib` but not `/usr/lib` or `/lib` (which are the same directory).  Why it's trying to do the latter, I can't say, but it seems wrong to me.

I would suggest looking to see if there are any ways to influence where Python is installed when doing so the way you are doing.  If you are open to installing Python with Homebrew, then I'll tell you that it's a way to go that has never let me down.  You should know about an extension to `pyenv` called `pyenv-register` that makes it easier to register pre-installed Python versions with `pyenv`, although there are also instructions on the web explaining how to do so without it.  I've used both methods with success.  In both cases, I go back in and define extra aliases for my Python versions, much like `pyenv` seems to do when it installs a Python version.  I'd be happy to help you if you want to explore this route.